# DD Android to PC is not copying

Tags: android, dd

I have to do a forensic analysis on a device (GT-I9505) for my thesis and I'm trying to get an image of the user data partition.

Device is rooter, with custom recovery and busybox as well. I followed a tutorial I found from another topic and it works but not as it should be, I think.

I have run this

```
adb forward tcp:5555 tcp:5555
adb shell
su
/system/xbin/busybox nc -l -p 5555 -e /system/xbin/busybox dd if=/dev/block/mmcblk0p29
```

[image: blocks]

My problem is that from time to time this is what is happening.  Is it normal?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

I did it again and i left my computer all night without doing anything else and it worked. I don't what was the problem before but it works now.